# Jpeg metadata for adobe format

Tags: adobe, metadata, jpeg, xmp, iptc

I downloaded xnview two years ago, and added title/subject/keywords metadata for a bunch of jpegs. However recently I compared the keywords from xnview and adobe bridge. I realize that they are different. I believe the title/subject is not the same. I noticed this, because some stock photo agencies do not read the metadata from xnview. They usually leave the title field blank. It looks like xnview uses xmp format whereas adobe uses iptc. Any suggestions on how I can batch convert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does Adobe software support IPTC metadata these days? They are authors of XMP which is a competing standard, so I wonder. Also, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform#Support_and_acceptance for a list of software with which you can check actual content of the metadata for the particular file (I would suggest http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/ as the most versatile option).

Comment: Thanks. I was using xnview for a few years. I recently started using adobe bridge. I'm trying to figure out how to move all the metadata from xnview format to adobe bridge format. From my google searches, I assumed that xnview uses xmp format and bridge uses iptc. I'll check again.